# pHash (image-hash) in objective-c doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, macos, phash

i used brew to create a compiled library from phash
i have imported the CImg.h file and everything compiles but it doesn't work.

i want to make a hash from an image but i always get the same output

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForImageResource:@"branch.png"];

const char *image = [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

ulong64 hash = 0;
int valid = ph_dct_imagehash(image,hash);

NSLog(@"%i",valid);
NSLog(@"%llu",hash);
```

With this output

```
 sh: convert: command not found
 sh: gm: command not found
 sh: convert: command not found
 sh: gm: command not found
 sh: convert: command not found
 sh: gm: command not found
 2011-10-03 20:10:22.571 pHashi386[2155:60b] -1
 2011-10-03 20:10:22.572 pHashi386[2155:60b] 0
```

cleary something goes wrong but i don't have a clue what the sh commands not found are and neither if i'm on the right track.

Comment: Do you know what script it wants to run? The convert could be the one from ImageMagick.

Comment: yeah its the one from ImageMagick and GM is graphicsmagick and i both installed them with brew. if i do "sh" and terminal and then typ convert it works.. but if i compile my project in xcode it keeps nagging about the command not found .. the convert and gm commands are used by CImg.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems i had to add a enviroment variable PATH

i used /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin

as my value

i'm not quite sure if it would work on the iOS platform though.

Comment: You could bundle it with your app, see the iOS downloads at http://www.imagemagick.org/download/iOS/

Answer (score 0):

You also can tell CImg where to find ImageMagic convert, example:

cimg::imagemagick_path("/opt/local/bin/convert");